# Should reloading nginx config only work when changing config file specified on start?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Based on what I've read, it looks like I should be able to specify a new configuration file path when running nginx reload:

```
sudo nginx -c ${config_file_path} -s reload
```

But what I'm finding is that the config argument will only set the config to be loaded when initially starting nginx. So if I started nginx using...

```
sudo nginx -c /path/to/first/config/nginx.conf
```

Then later I create a different path /path/to/second/config/nginx.conf and try to run...

```
sudo nginx -c /path/to/second/config/nginx.conf -s reload
```

The second configuration is not loaded. In my logs/errors.log I see [notice] PID/PID: signal process started, but what's reloaded are really changes to /path/to/first/config/nginx.conf, even though I specified the second config in the reload call.

Is this expected behavior? Namely that -c argument when starting nginx will set the configuration value to be used until nginx is stopped, and the parameter really has no effect on subsequent reload calls?

For what it's worth, this is my nginx version information:

```
nginx version: openresty/1.19.9.1
built by gcc 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021)
TLS SNI support enabled
arguments:
--prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx
--with-cc-opt='-O2
-DNGX_LUA_ABORT_AT_PANIC
-I/usr/local/openresty/zlib/include
-I/usr/local/openresty/pcre/include
-I/usr/local/openresty/openssl111/include'
--add-module=../ngx_devel_kit-0.3.1
--add-module=../echo-nginx-module-0.62
--add-module=../xss-nginx-module-0.06
--add-module=../ngx_coolkit-0.2
--add-module=../set-misc-nginx-module-0.32
--add-module=../form-input-nginx-module-0.12
--add-module=../encrypted-session-nginx-module-0.08
--add-module=../srcache-nginx-module-0.32
--add-module=../ngx_lua-0.10.20
--add-module=../ngx_lua_upstream-0.07
--add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.33
--add-module=../array-var-nginx-module-0.05
--add-module=../memc-nginx-module-0.19
--add-module=../redis2-nginx-module-0.15
--add-module=../redis-nginx-module-0.3.7
--add-module=../ngx_stream_lua-0.0.10
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib
-L/usr/local/openresty/zlib/lib
-L/usr/local/openresty/pcre/lib
-L/usr/local/openresty/openssl111/lib
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/openresty/zlib/lib:/usr/local/openresty/pcre/lib:/usr/local/openresty/openssl111/lib'
--with-cc='ccache
gcc
-fdiagnostics-color=always'
--with-pcre-jit
--with-stream
--with-stream_ssl_module
--with-stream_ssl_preread_module
--with-http_v2_module
--without-mail_pop3_module
--without-mail_imap_module
--without-mail_smtp_module
--with-http_stub_status_module
--with-http_realip_module
--with-http_addition_module
--with-http_auth_request_module
--with-http_secure_link_module
--with-http_random_index_module
--with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_sub_module
--with-http_dav_module
--with-http_flv_module
--with-http_mp4_module
--with-http_gunzip_module
--with-threads
--with-compat
--with-stream
--with-http_ssl_module
```

Answer (score 0):

The config file path feed into `nginx -c` is mostly let the ad-hoc nginx process know where to read the pid file(it's `pid` directive inside config file), not for the daemon nginx process reloading config.